# Elimination from a Trigonometric Equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here is the question:

Eliminate $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ from the
equations
$$\boldsymbol{4(\cos\alpha\cos\theta+\cos\varphi)(\cos\alpha\sin\theta+\sin\varphi)}$$
$$\boldsymbol{=4(\cos\alpha\cos\theta+\cos\psi)(\cos\alpha\sin\theta+\sin\psi)}$$
$$\boldsymbol{=(\cos\varphi-\cos\psi)(\sin\varphi-\sin\psi)}$$

and
prove
that $\boldsymbol{\cos(\varphi-\psi)=1}$ or $\boldsymbol{\cos 2\alpha}$

Its probably not that difficult but not having much success at the moment, so I thought I would post it here.

Comment: @Somos Thanks, good call, ill fix that.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a not-quite-elegant solution: Abbreviating the system as $P=Q=R$ we can get
$$\begin{align}
P+Q=2R &\quad\to\quad (2\cos\alpha\cos\theta+ \cos\phi + \cos\psi ) (2 \cos\alpha \sin\theta+\sin\phi + \sin\psi )=0 \\[0.5em]
&\quad\to\quad \phantom{\text{OR}}\cos\alpha\cos\theta=-\frac12(\cos\phi+\cos\psi) \\[0.5em]
&\phantom{\quad\to\quad}\;\text{OR}\;
\cos\alpha\sin\theta=-\frac12(\sin\phi+\sin\psi) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Substituting these options into $P=Q$ gives
$$\begin{align}
(\cos\phi - \cos\psi) (2 \cos\alpha \sin\theta + \sin\phi + \sin\psi) &=0 \\
\text{OR} \quad (\sin\phi - \sin\psi)(2 \cos\alpha \cos\theta + \cos\phi + \cos\psi )  &= 0
\end{align}$$
Thus, we find that *either* $\phi$ and $\psi$ have equal sines and cosines (making them equal *modulo* $2\pi$), so that
$$\cos(\phi-\psi)=\cos0=1$$
*or else* the "OR" in (1) should be "AND", so that
$$\begin{align}\cos^2\alpha&=\frac14(\cos\phi+\cos\psi)^2+\frac14(\sin\phi+\sin\psi)^2=\frac12(1+\cos(\phi-\psi))\\[0.5em]
\to \cos(\phi-\psi)&=\cos2\alpha
\end{align}$$
as desired. $\square$

I wonder if there's a particular geometric configuration behind OP's system that might give rise to a more straightforward solution.

Comment: Yes, I like this solution. Why is it not elegant ? It is probably what was intended.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I don't really care for the breakdown into cases, especially since one of the logical paths back-tracks to assert that *both* relations in (1) must hold. I suspect there's a unified approach. ... What's the source of the exercise?

Comment: I think cases are intrinsic to the question. Its from Hobson Treatise on Plane Trigonometry.

Comment: The same question appears in Nixon's *Trigonometry* (Page 166) with a minor variation. Probably that could give an insight for the elegant solution. Although the current solution seems elegant as well. : )

Answer (score 0):

One method using Computer Algebra Systems is to use a substitution and factorization. The expressions are:

$$t_1 := 4(\cos\alpha\cos\theta+\cos\varphi)(\cos\alpha\sin\theta+\sin\varphi), \tag{1}$$
$$t_2 := 4(\cos\alpha\cos\theta+\cos\psi)(\cos\alpha\sin\theta+\sin\psi), \tag{2}$$
$$t_3 :=(\cos\varphi-\cos\psi)(\sin\varphi-\sin\psi),
\tag{3}$$
$$t_4 :=(\cos(\varphi-\psi)-1)
(\cos(\varphi-\psi)-\cos(2\alpha)). \tag{4}$$
Let
$$t_5 := t_2-t_1,\qquad t_6 := t_3-t_1. \tag{5}$$
Now use the substitutions
$$\alpha=\frac{\log(X)}i,\,
  \theta=\frac{\log(Y)}i,\,
  \varphi=\frac{\log(Z)}i,\,
  \psi=\frac{\log(W)}i. \tag{6}$$
We want to eliminate $\,Y\,$ between $\,t_5\,$ and
$\,t_6\,$. Let $\,t_7\,$ be the resultant of the
numerators of $\,t_5\,$ and $\,t_6\,$ eliminating
$\,Y\,$. Note that
$$ t_4 = \frac{(W-Z)^2(W-X^2Z)(WX^2-Z)}{(2WXZ)^2}
\tag{7}$$ and that
$$ t_8:=t_7/t_4^2 = (4X^2 W^5 Z^5(1+X^2)^2(1-W^2Z^2))^2. \tag{8}$$
Of the factors in $\,t_8\,$ none of $\,X,Z,W\,$ are
zero. If $\,1+X^2=0\,$ then $\,\alpha=\pm\pi/2,\,$
$\,\cos(2\alpha)-1=0\,$ and this is in $\,t_4.\,$
If $\,1-W^2Z^2=0\,$ then $\,\varphi=\pm\psi,\,$
$\,\cos\varphi-\cos\psi=0\,$ and this is also in $\,t_4.\,$